# Cursor Size not changing

Tags: release-loki, display, system

Could any one please help me. I have an issue with cursor size. Since I'm using a 4k display, most DEs seem to make cursors huge and with the sizing bug. I have tried dconf-editor to change the size and theme of the cursor, but this, for some reason, works correctly on applications only. When moving the cursor out any application window, the mouse becomes bigger.

I've got the themes synced with update-alternatives for the outside application windows themes,and dconf for inside windows theme.

Anything to do with elementary's DE gui causes the sizing issue.
Bare in mind, dconf sorted this issue out on other ubuntu distros.

I've made a ~/.Xresources with Xcursor.size: 16 in it, which has not worked. The application window cursor looks like size 16 whilst outside looks 32.

Images of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BYN0.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing cursor-theme to elementary? That worked for me when I had the same issue.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it explained how to change the cursor theme

Comment: Excuse me but I've used elementary long ago and my answer could be therefore inaccurate. I remember installing some package (with gui) through which you could customize most of the defaults by supplying number or string values but I don't remember the name and how to exactly do it.